# The equivalent of .get In Deque

Tags: java

so recently I've been wanting to work with Deque more in Java and I kind of ran into a little problem...

For an ArrayList/List I can use .get such as:
getAge().get(3) (Bad example, sorry)

What I am trying to do is do the equivalent in Deque, but not really sure how.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There isn't an equivalent. Think in terms of queues and stacks and throw away the whole idea of random access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html):

> A linear collection that supports element insertion and removal at both ends.
>
> ...
>
> This interface defines methods to access the elements at both ends of the deque.

A `Deque` does not support random access retrieval, as it's essentially a double-ended queue.

If all you're interested in are the elements at the head and tail, then use a `Deque`.  If you want to be able to peek at elements efficiently (random access), then use a `Collection` that supports that (such as an `ArrayList`).

If you refuse to use anything other than a `Deque`, then it's possible to poll elements (storing them in another `Deque`) until you reach the index you're interested in.  However, that is essentially emulating a `LinkedList`.